# A-Level Core Mathematics 1 - Differentiation Question

Tags: calculus

[image]

What's the thought process when confronted with a question like this.
After a year this is the first time I've seen a question like this, in C1.

I've worked out $$y'' =  \frac{3}{2x^{1/2}}$$

How do I then go to the equation including k, where does the k even come from?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to substitute the expression you found for the second derivative and the expression for $y$ into the expression
$$4x^2y''  - 3y$$
which yields
$$4x^2\left(\frac{3}{2x^{1/2}}\right) - 3\left(2x^{3/2} - 1\right)$$
If you simplify that expression, you will determine the value of $k$.

Comment: 1. What does the value of k represent?
2. What does the "4y′′−3y" formula represent / what are it's applications?

Comment: The number $k$ is just a constant.   To me, this looks like an exercise designed to check whether you have calculated the second derivative correctly.  The coefficients of $y''$ and $y$ are chosen so that when you simplify the expression, the result is a constant.  This is a second order [Cauchy-Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation) differential equation.  I am not familiar with its applications.

Comment: Honestly, I'm still baffled. Throughout the curriculum the equation "4y''-3y" is never mentioned so I'm assuming it was improvised, how was that done? 

How do I go from Y'' and Y to the formula including K?

Comment: Let's simplify.  $$4x^2\left(\frac{3}{2x^{1/2}}\right) - 3(2x^{3/2} - 1) = 6x^{3/2} - 6x^{3/2} + 3 = 3$$  so $k = 3$. The factor of $x^2$ was clearly chosen so that both terms with variables would have the same power.  The factors of $4$ and $-3$ were chosen so that the terms with variables would cancel out.

Comment: I understand the substitution... but if the question was looking for me to find the value of k, surely it would say something like "given that 4xy.... = k, find the value of k" not "show that 4xy... = k"

Comment: Is the statement of the question complete?

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: The reason I asked that question whether the question is complete is that part (b) ends with a comma.  I think the point of the exercise is to demonstrate that the second derivative satisfies the differential equation $4x^2y'' - 3y = 3$.  Asking you to determine the value of $k$ is just an algebra exercise.

Comment: Another way to show that the expession $4x^2y'' - 3y$ is constant would be to show that its derivative is zero.  However, to show that $k$ is an integer, you would have to do what I did.